the difference between scopes in gradle simple application and android application
I'm new to the world of gradle, actually I want to know the diffirents scopes in gradle simple application, actually as I see there is runtimeClasspath and compiletimeClasspath for simple gradle application, but when it comes to android application with gradle there are diffirents,like releaseRuntimeClasspath ..., i want to know each one and why it's used, also for the task dependencies that shows the tree of dependencies, it takes an argument --configuration to specify the scope.
is there is any way so i can pass two scope at the same command, please ?
